# Before taming fire, what did early humans do in dark?

Tags: anthropology

Obviously, they can't go to sleep immediately after sunset right?

Comment: How is this a question about psychology?

Comment: Anthropology is related to psychology - https://www.quora.com/How-closely-tied-are-anthropology-and-psychology-as-fields-of-study

Comment: Anthropology may be related to Psychology @pinpinokio but the crux of the question (what did they do) is not. If it was *”what did they think”* it would be on topic if it could be answered without opinion. I have voted to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest where I can post this question.....I didn't find Anthropology  in meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SwamiSriman I think this is certainly an *interesting* question, but there may not be an SE site for it. There are [almost 200 SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) now, and there is a process for starting new ones if enough interest is shown. Also, from time to time people will ask in the "[main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)" site about the best place to ask a question. I think that the `scope` tag should be used there. Keep your question clear, i.e. "is there an SE site for this kind of question" rather than "why can't I ask my question..." if you decide to ask there.

Comment: @SwamiSriman Please refer to this:
https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/255/26103

I think it could be on-topic if you could you express your interest on the behavior on the individual level (so it's in psychology). Otherwise, if your interest is on the social level, then you'd have to connect it to sociology, per the answer in the link.